# Is there any good site for finding/voting/discussing ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

[RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/), the official gems site, provides poor functions. I want to find some good gems for my website, but it's impossible—it only provides several *"New Gems"* / *"Most downloaded today"* gems, and a list of all gems by indices. And the "search" is poor as well.

Anyone know any good site for finding/voting and discussing gems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) is quite useful to find gems. They are sorted in categories and ranked by the amount of watchers/forks on github. No voting/discussions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you figure out something you want to do, then search for a gem, not browse through gems on the off chance you hit functionality you find useful.

That said, you could search github: http://github.com/search?type=Repositories&q=gem

But the best idea would probably be to go look through other open source projects and see what they're using.

Comment: when I look for extensions of firefox and chrome, I found they have a really good web site. It's easy for a beginner to find good extensions they want. Hope there is a website like them for gems.